# como leer un procedimiento almacenado en controlado MVC asp.net?

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedure, controller

quisiera poder ejecutar un procedimiento en el controlador:

```
public ActionResult Linea()
    {
        

        return View(vista);
    }
```

Añadi un model para cargar el procedimiento, no tengo ninguna tabla, ya que no me es necesario, la consulta es grande para trabajar desde EF por eso cree el SP
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se como puedo hacer para que mi controlador lo ejecute y ya despues mandarlo a la vista

Comment: context.Database .SqlQuery<SP_retorna_blabla>("EXECUTE dbo.sp_nombre"). Igual no entiendo porque alguien preferiría hacer un store procedure en vez de ocupar linq

Comment: @Yussef no me funciono.. seguire probando gracias